# Right-aligning TikZ nodes - bug?

Tags: tikz-node, alignment

I've just wasted over an hour trying to figure out why vertically-stacked nodes weren't right-aligning as I'd expect. Turns out, simply changing the order of the `anchor` and `below` attributes is enough to trigger the problem.

A MWE is:

```
% !TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={draw=black}]
        \node (first)  [box] {first};
        \node (second) [box,below=0mm of first.south east,anchor=north east] {second};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={draw=black}]
        \node (first)  [box] {first};
        \node (second) [box,anchor=north east,below=0mm of first.south east] {second};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

As you can see, the alignment works in the first case, but not the second. The only difference is the ordering of the attributes.

Can anyone confirm this is a bug, or am I misunderstanding some expected behavior here?

Comment: The below key sets also the anchor.

Comment: The `below` key (or any positioning keys) defines implicitly an anchor (see p.230, pgfmanual).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as mentioned [Paul Gaborit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14500/paul-gaborit)  any positioning keys defines implicitly an anchor. it also overwrite explicit written anchor, if it follows it.

to what you like to obtain is sufficient to use only positioning keys:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}% not use in real document! it show only both images
%\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}


\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 1pt and 0pt,
       box/.style = {draw=black}
                        ]
        \node (first)  [box] {first};
        \node (second) [box,below right=of first.south west] {second};
    \end{tikzpicture}

     \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 0pt,
       box/.style = {draw=black}
                        ]
        \node (first)  [box] {first};
        \node (second) [box,below left=of first.south east] {second};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I mark it as an answer somewhat reluctantly, not because it wasn't a useful reply (it totally was), but because it seems to me that this kind of unexpected behavior should be considered a bug. It matters not to me that it's explained away at page 230 (!) of the manual. Anyway, thanks again.